# Overwriting Python Path in xlwings

Tags: python, excel, git, python-import, xlwings

I have two repositories in my file structure R1 and R2.  Repository 1 (R1) is in my PYTHONPATH.

I'm trying out xlwings which works wonderfully when I run from Python to change an Excel file.  However, I'm having issues with running scripts from Repository 2 (R2).

When I put the path to R2 in PYTHONPATH in the xlwings addin it seems to be *appending* R2 onto the original PYTHONPATH and since R1 is first it seems to be defaulting to R1 when importing.

Is there a way to (locally) overwrite the PYTHONPATH just for that xlwings instance well keeping R1 in my system PYTHONPATH?

Comment: shooting in the dark here but do relative imports work?

Comment: @Yuca Relative imports don't seem to work either...

Comment: Make sure your pythonpath points to the parent directory of your package

Comment: OK I think I'm close.  I think PYTHONPATH in xlwings doesn't overwrite the PYTHONPATH it merely appends.  So my imports are looking at my main repository not the working repository.  Is there a way to overwrite?

Comment: @FelixZumstein Thanks for the comment.  It helped get me to the above understanding. You seem to be the expert here any ideas on my modified problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a config file in the directory of the workbook or a config sheet in the workbook itself, see: http://docs.xlwings.org/en/stable/addin.html#global-config-ribbon-config-file
These will override the settings from the global ribbon config.

Comment: So I tried the xlwings.conf method.  (Win10, xlwings 0.11.8)  Like changing the PYTHONPATH in the add-in.  This seems to merely append the new path on the global path instead of overwriting it.   I might have a work around that would allow me to completely remove pythonpath from my system permanently which would hopefully solve the issue.